# String to Time using For Loop in Data Frame

Tags: python, for-loop, time, dataframe

I hate to think how long I've spent on trying to fix this trivial issue, but I'm trying to convert a string into a date for every row in a particular column. The below is my data frame:

```
table:
        day date            rankgross_budget
    0   Fri Sep. 18, 2015   5   $2,298,380
    1   Sat Sep. 19, 2015   5   $2,993,960
    2   Sun Sep. 20, 2015   5   $1,929,695
    3   Mon Sep. 21, 2015   5   $617,410
    4   Tue Sep. 22, 2015   5   $851,220
```

My unsuccessful attempt of changing date to a date format goes as so:

```
for d in table.date :
        table.date[d] = time.strptime(table.date[d],'%b. %d, %Y')
```

And I'm getting thrown this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3704)()

pandas/hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:7200)()

TypeError: an integer is required

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-cc64c6038ec8> in <module>()
     21 
     22 for d in table.date :
---> 23         table.date[d] = time.strptime(table.date[d],'%b. %d, %Y')
     24 
     25 table.head()

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    519     def __getitem__(self, key):
    520         try:
--> 521             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    522 
    523             if not np.isscalar(result):

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/index.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   1593 
   1594         try:
-> 1595             return self._engine.get_value(s, k)
   1596         except KeyError as e1:
   1597             if len(self) > 0 and self.inferred_type in ['integer','boolean']:

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/index.c:3113)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/index.c:2844)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3761)()

KeyError: 'Sep. 18, 2015'
```

Where am I going wrong? Any help on this would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access a value with `table.date[d]` that doesn't have an index of value `'Sep. 18, 2015'`, hence the `KeyError`. Printing the `table.date` column you'll see that this is what it looks like:

```
In [19]: df.date
Out[19]: 
0    Sep. 18, 2015
1    Sep. 19, 2015
Name: date, dtype: object
```

---

You should generally use the `apply()` method to do this, `apply()` takes a function as an argument and applies it to a column you specify:

```
# Create the function that transforms the string.
to_time = lambda x: time.strptime(x,'%b. %d, %Y')

# Pass it to apply for the column "date".
table["date"] = table["date"].apply(to_time)
```

For mock data the result is:

```
Out[17]: 
0    (2015, 9, 18, 0, 0, 0, 4, 261, -1)
1    (2015, 9, 19, 0, 0, 0, 5, 262, -1)
Name: date, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

One simple option would be to use `to_datetime()`.

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

Gives you:

```
df['date']
0   2015-09-18
1   2015-09-19
2   2015-09-20
3   2015-09-21
4   2015-09-22
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was after. Must read documentation more thoroughly for pandas. Cheers rurp